# error filter is not a function when I use an interface []

Tags: arrays, typescript, interface

I have this interface:

```
export interface IPevMoldMapPayload {
  mold: IMold;
  updateCurrentMold?: boolean;
  datetime?: number;
  username?: string;
 }
```

In another class I use this:

```
...
moldHistory: IPevMoldMapPayload[] = [];
...
```

fill moldHistory with some data and filter that

```
...
if (this.moldHistory.length > 0) {
  let filteredHistory = this.moldHistory.filter((item) => 
    item.datetime>=Date.now() - hourSelected);
}
...
```

here I have this error: "filter is not a function"

Any Idea??

Thank ;)

Comment: Please paste here all log messages. Isn't this.moldHistory undefined? What is the exact error?

Comment: If I change moldHistory: IPevMoldMapPayload[] = [] with 
moldHistory: any[] = [];
the error disappear!!!

Comment: If I change moldHistory: IPevMoldMapPayload[] = [] with moldHistory: any[] = []; the error disappear!!! .... this is bad solution, if you are doing such things you dont need typescript... check what type is this.moldHistory. if it is for ex. string it will pass the length condition but will have no filter option. Use any if there is no other solution